# Android split text via voice command

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I have implemented voice commands on my app to make it easier for the user to set variables, I have tried using `StringTokenizer` to split the commands so I only get the variable but that doesn't seem to work, can someone point me in the right direction?

```
 @Override
public void OnResult(ArrayList<String> commands) {
    for(String command:commands)
    {
       if (command.contains("set amount to")){
       StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(command, "to");
        String first = tokens.nextToken();
        String second = tokens.nextToken();

           Log.e("TAG", command);
           Log.e("TAG", "First " + first);
           Log.e("TAG", "Second " + second);
       }
    }
}
```

The command I give is for example `set amount to 5` and it comes back as `First se` and `Second am` and I am not sure how to make it find the 5 or if they add on additional words after like `5 dollars` I don't want to pick up the dollars.